# Reverse list using map/reduce

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce

I am learning concepts of functional programming and trying out problem exercises.
An exercise, 
Reverse a list using map/reduce.
My solution:

```
lists = [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ,6]

def tree_reverse(lists):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: a + [a.insert(0,x)], lists, [])

print tree_reverse(lists)
```

Output:

```
[6, 5, 3, 2, 1, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I don't understand why there are Nones equal to number of elements in list.

EDIT: Extending question for case of nested lists.

```
 lists = [ 1 ,2 ,3 , [5,6,7], 8, [9, 0, 1 ,4 ]]
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider practicing with `reduce()` - it's been removed entirely from Python 3.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 not entirely, it is still available in `functools`.

Comment: Thanks for info.  I will look more details about it. Still what to know what's wrong in above code principly.

Comment: Using `insert` goes against the very essence of functional programming. You are not supposed to mutate anything.

Comment: Instead do it like `return reduce(lambda a, x: [x] + a, lists, [])` and remember that this is not a very efficient operation in python and also that python will eventually hit a limit on the number of recursive calls it can do.

Comment: In case of nested list ?  I do 
    
    `def tree_reverse(lists):
        return reduce(lambda a, x: (tree_reverse(x) if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) + a  , lists, [])`

It gives me flatten reverse list.  I want to reverse and still keep it nested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, i don't know Python good enough, but as you marked the question as "functional-programming" and you stated you want to learn in general about functional programming i want to give some general explanation of your problem. 
At first, you should rethink what the `map` and `reduce` operation do and what they expect. Let's start with the `map` function.

A `map` function for a list (in functional programming you don't have only one map, you have one map for every generic type) executes a function on every single argument. That function can operate on that single argument and transform it. The result of this transformation is turned into a new list. One important note is that the function you pass to `map` only ever sees one element, so you cannot use `map` itself to transform a list as a whole. You only can transform every single element of a list. But changing the order needs the idea of having at least two elements of a list, and a map only ever gets a single element. This is the reason why the reverse logic cannot be in `map` and has to be part of the `reduce` operation.

The `reduce` function on the other hand expects a function that takes two things of the same type, and returns a single item of the same type. For example the reduce function could take the "+" function. "+" is a function that takes two `int` and returns a new `int`. The signature is basically `int + int = int`. The essence of reduce is to take two things and turn it into a single new item. If you for example had something more complex like a class "Foo", then the function you have to provide to reduce need to have the signature `Foo * Foo -> Foo`. Meaning take a `Foo` as first and second argument, and return a single new `Foo`.

It is also important to note how `reduce` will work with that function. Let's assume you have the List `[1,2,3,4,5]` on top let's assume you have an `accumulator function` that takes two `int` that just adds them together. What you can think of what will happen is the following.

1. The `reduce` function takes the first two arguments of your list (1 and 2 in this case)
2. Passes those to the `accumulator function` (1 + 2 = 3)
3. And replaces the two arguments in the list with the result. [3,3,4,5]
4. Go back to 1) and repeat that process until your List only have a single item
5. Return that single item

So what you can imagine what happens is the following

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> 1 + 2 = 3
[3,3,4,5]   -> 3 + 3 = 6
[6,4,5]     -> 6 + 4 = 10
[10,5]      -> 10 + 5 = 15
[15]        -> Return just "15". Not a "[15]"
```

Actually the process internal usually works a little bit different. But this is the process you can imagine what happens. It is important to note that you never modify a list. You always create new lists in that process. Another important note. At the end of the `reduce` function you have a list of an single item. But the `reduce` function does not return the whole list. It returns just the single element. So you get `15` an `int` as a result. You don't get a list with a single item containing `15`. Reduce will just return that single element. Whatever it is. One other way to think about it. You always get exactly the type back of your `accumulator function`. If you pass a `accumulator function` that takes two `int` adds them and returns a new `int`. Your reduce function will also return an `int`. If you pass an `accumulator function` that takes two `Foo` classes and returns a new `Foo`. Your `reduce` function will also return a `Foo` as its result. The return type of `reduce` is always the same as the types of your `accumulator function`.

Now let's take all those pieces and put them together. The goal is to reverse a list. The first important thing is. Your result type will be a `list`. That also means that the function you pass into `reduce` also have to return a `list`. But as the input are always the same as the output. You now have to provide a `accumulator function` that takes two lists, and returns a single new list.

But now let's step back. What happens if you use your list "[1,2,3,4,5]" directly as the input to reduce? The short answer is, it will not work. `reduce` will take two argument of your list. But what you have is a list of int. But your `accumulator function` expects two lists not two int. To solve that problem, what you now can do is try to convert every single element of the list into its own list. So how do we transform every single element of a list? Right! With `map`! So what you have to do is the following. You first map your list into a list of lists.

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

Now your reduce function gets the first two elements of your first list. It means you now have an accumulator function that gets `[1]` and `[2]` as its argument. Two separate lists. But your accumulator function has to return a single new list. If unclear, just remind what the accumulator function takes and return.

```
int, int    -> int
float,float -> float
Foo,Foo     -> Foo
list,list   -> list
```

So what you now have to do is to combine those two lists into a single new list. Or in other words you have to append/concat those two lists. I don't knew exactly how you concat two lists in Python let's assume here the operation would be "++". So if you concat just the first argument and the second argument, you will not get what you want.

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] -> [1]       ++ [2] = [1,2]
[[1,2],[3],[4],[5]]   -> [1,2]     ++ [3] = [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[4],[5]]     -> [1,2,3]   ++ [4] = [1,2,3,4]
[[1,2,3,4],[5]]       -> [1,2,3,4] ++ [5] = [1,2,3,4,5]
[[1,2,3,4,5]]         -> Return first element [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So what you have to do is to concat the second argument with the first one.

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] -> [2] ++ [1]       = [2,1]
[[2,1],[3],[4],[5]]   -> [3] ++ [2,1]     = [3,2,1]
[[3,2,1],[4],[5]]     -> [4] ++ [3,2,1]   = [4,3,2,1]
[[4,3,2,1],[5]]       -> [5] ++ [4,3,2,1] = [5,4,3,2,1]
[[5,4,3,2,1]]         -> Return first element [5,4,3,2,1]
```

And now what you get is your reversed list. So what you have todo

1. map every element to a list. So you get a list of list
2. use reduce to concat every list of list into a new list in reversed order.

For example, in F# the whole code would look like this.

```f#
let list = [1;2;3;4;5]

let reversed =
    list
    |> List.map    (fun x -> [x]) // map every element to a list
    |> List.reduce (fun xs ys -> List.append ys xs) // Note ys ++ xs - reversed order for appending

printfn "%A" reversed
// prints: [5;4;3;2;1]
```

I think you should be able to translate this to Python. As a further notice. Doing "map" and then a "concat" operation (without reversing) is also named "bind" in functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

Your reduce operation is appending a `None` to the end of the list `a` because `a.insert(0,x)` will return `None`.

So you are modifying the list `a` in-place, but appending a `None` value at the same time.

If you rewrite your `reduce` operation to use a `for` loop, it'd look like:

```
def reverse_list(lists):
    r = []
    for x in lists:
        val = r.insert(0,x)
        r = r + [val]  # val (the return value of r.insert) is None
    return r
```

Comment: Why does it return None ? a is accumulator list and a.insert(0,x) should insert.  is it wrong ?

Comment: `insert` modifies the list *in-place* rather than returning a *brand-new modified list*, and in python, a method that doesn't return explicitly any value, implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Note the difference between modifying an object *in-place* vs creating a new object. That the difference between `a.insert(0,x)` vs `a = [x] + a`. If you want to go by the functional way you should avoid the side-effects of changing thing in-place.

Answer (score 0):

In case of nested list. I am posting answer for reference.

```
lists = [ 1 ,2 ,3 , [5,6,7], 8, [9, 0, 1 ,4 ]]

def tree_reverse(lists):
    return  reduce(lambda a, x: ( map(tree_reverse, [x]) if isinstance(x,list) else [x] ) + a  , lists , [] )

print tree_reverse(lists)
```

Output :

```
[[4, 1, 0, 9], 8, [7, 6, 5], 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming languages will often use recursion to implement iteration.

A recursive `tree_reverse` function might look like

```
def tree_reverse(lists):
    return tree_reverse(lists[1:]) + [lists[0]] if lists else []
```

If you look at Haskell it might be implemented like this

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' [] = []  
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Where the `x` is the head of the list (first element) and `xs` is the tail (the list minus the head) and you can see that `reverse'` is called recursively with those elements reversed and the reversed list is built up iteratively.