# Cool ways to use reduce()?

Tags: python

I was recently talking to a friend and he said that you can use Python's reduce() function for example to calculate the length of a list or even reverse a list. I tried to google the actual code, but I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Those are actually really bad uses of reduce, especially because getting the length and reversing a list is something that is available as a built-in already. Read this for some better examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995/useful-code-which-uses-reduce-in-python

Comment: Those are some interesting examples, thank you for the link, but they don't talk about reversing a list or getting the length. Could you do that too?

Comment: Why would you want to do that with reduce? If you want to get the length of a list, do `len(my_list)`. If you want to reverse a list, do `my_list.reverse()`. And searching your question on SO actually brings [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908847/reverse-list-using-map-reduce). Maybe that will help give you more information

Comment: In other languages, `reduce` might be called `fold`. You may find examples using that term.

Comment: You really shouldn't do it this way because there are better ways, but you can use `reduce(lambda x, y: x+1, mylist, 0)` to get the length and `reduce(lambda x, y: [y] + x, mylist, [])` to get the reversed list.

Comment: I think `[::-1]` is cooler because it works exactly the same for strings and lists. It doesn't reverse in place. `["a", "b"][::-1]` -> `['b', 'a']` and `"ab"[::-1]` -> `'ba'`

Comment: There is a nice example of cumsum using reduce here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258602/elegant-pythonic-cumsum

Answer (score 1):

You really should use `len()` and `reversed()`, but if you want to use `reduce()`, you *can* do it:

```
length = reduce(lambda x,y: x+1, mylist, 0)

reverse = reduce(lambda x,y: [y]+x, mylist, [])
```

For the length, we just need to keep track of a running total in our function.  We therefore need to start out with a total of `0`.  That can be passed to `reduce()` as the `initial` argument.  Now, our function will first take the `initial` and the first element in `mylist`.  It just ignores the second argument (the first element in the list) and returns `x+1`.  Right now `x` is `0`, so it returns `1`.  Next that and the second element in `mylist` are given it.  It returns the first argument, `1` plus `1`: `2`.  It goes on like this until it reaches the end of `mylist` at which point it has the total.

For the reversing, it is very similar.  We start out with `x` being `[]`.  Then, we want to put the first element at the beginning, so we return `[y] + x`.  Next time it is called, it will be with `[y] + x` and the second element in `mylist`.  It then puts that second element at the beginning and returns that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce` can be a very powerful function in Python, along with `map` and `lambda` expressions. One example, is computing the sum of numbers from 1 to 100:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, range(1,101))
5050
```

You can also use it to find the max of a list:

```
>>> f = lambda a,b: a if (a > b) else b
>>> reduce(f, [47,11,42,102,13])
102
```

You can even use it to flatten lists (this is have found to be very useful):

```
reduce(list.__add__, [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You are aware that all of your three examples can be archived with the built-in functions `sum()` and `max()` in a far more simple way?